# BGAppRefreshTask not executing SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background, task

I'm getting inconsistent results when using the [Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks) framework for my application written in SwiftUI. I'm only looking to make quick network requests, so I'm choosing to use `BGAppRefreshTask`.

Background fetch, and Background Processing are set in Signing & Capabilities. Permitted background task scheduler identifiers have been set. Manually calling it in debugging works fine on a real device but never in production.

I tested both `BGAppRefreshTask`, and `BGProcessingTask`. I noticed BGProcessingTask is being called but only when connected to a power supply. I never see any updates from `BGAppRefreshTask`. I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple.

BGAppRefreshTask hasn't run for **FOUR days** now since updating this post. BGProcessingTask was run 13 time's overnight but only if my device is charging. Even when setting `requiresExternalPower` to false.

`BGAppRefreshTask run: 0` & `BGProcessingTask run: 13`

Calling in the debugger using commands [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development) works but it's never run on my device without simulating in the debugger.

```
(lldb) e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.bgapp.refresh"]
2022-02-26 11:41:33.964753-0800 BGAppRefreshTask[9180:2203525] Simulating launch for task with identifier com.bgapp.refresh
2022-02-26 11:41:35.908739-0800 BGAppRefreshTask[9180:2203542] Starting simulated task: <decode: missing data>
2022-02-26 11:41:35.912108-0800 BGAppRefreshTask[9180:2203542] Marking simulated task complete: <BGAppRefreshTask: com.bgapp.refresh>
Received completion: finished.
```

**UPDATE**

I used `getPendingTaskRequests` to see if any task was being registered and it's apparent it is but still not executing. The earliest date is scheduled for **19:28** so **7:28PM**. I registered my task at **11:23AM** but it's not schedule to run for another **8 hours**.

```
Pending task requests: [<BGAppRefreshTaskRequest: com.bgapp.refresh, earliestBeginDate: 2022-02-28 19:28:34 +0000>]
```

**BGAppRefresh**

```swift
/*!
 BGAppRefreshTask
 @abstract A background task used to update your app's contents in the background.
 */
class BGADelegate: NSObject,  UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    let taskIdentifier = "com.bgapp.refresh"
    @AppStorage("backgroundtask") var tasks: Int = 0
    
    func application(_ applicatiown: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        register()
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        return true
    }

    func register() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
            print("register")
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier)
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        task.expirationHandler = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tasks += 1
        }
        // Network request here
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        print("handle app refresh")
    }
    
}
```

**BGProcessingTask**

```swift
/*!
 BGProcessingTask
 @abstract A background task used to perform deferrable processing.
 */
class BGPDelegate: NSObject,  UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    let taskIdentifier = "com.bgapp.refresh"
    @AppStorage("backgroundtask") var tasks: Int = 0
    
    func application(_ applicatiown: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        register()
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        return true
    }

    func register() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
            print("register")
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier)
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true
        request.requiresExternalPower = false // Default value in false
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGProcessingTask) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        task.expirationHandler = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.backgroundtask += 1
        }
        // Network request here
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        print("handle app refresh")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for Apple rather than for us? I think you proved _you_ are doing everything right, so wouldn't this be a matter of how BGAppRefreshTask behaves in the field?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the nature of background tasks is that it's totally up to your system when they get run. Could be never. Think of this as _optional._ If this was important to do, then a background task wasn't the way to do it.

Comment: I asked on the Apple developer forum without an answer months ago! I found my problem by checking my my pending requests. Answer is below, I was opening the app and checking and further setting back the earlier date schedule to launch my background task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from new understanding of `Background Tasks`, I know now it's being scheduled for an earliest date but I was opening the application setting back the date it's scheduled for. I was not waiting past the earlier date scheduled when relaunching the application. Each task will be overwritten when setting the background app refresh task.

```swift
struct BGAppRefreshTaskApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor var delegate: AppDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(delegate)
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .background:
                        delegate.scheduleAppRefresh()
                        delegate.background += 1
                        print("background")
                    case .active:
                        print("active")
                        BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests(completionHandler: { request in
                            print("Pending task requests: \(request)")
                        })
                    case .inactive:
                        print("inactive")
                    @unknown default:
                        break
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool but that answer does not emerge from the question as asked.

Comment: It does though, the tasks are schedule for execution and now will work when waiting past the scheduled time of launch. I assumed launching the application wouldn't of change the initial registered task date scheduled. But I was wrong, it overwrites the registered task every launch then.

Comment: Right, thanks! That's clearer I think.